# Collapsed margin in CSS

Tags: css

MDN explains collapsed margin [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

These are the basic 3 rules it explains:

> **Adjacent siblings**
>
> The margins of adjacent siblings are collapsed (except when the later
>   sibling needs to be cleared past floats).
>
> **Parent and first/last child**
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline content,
>   block_formatting_context created or clearance to separate the
>   margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block, or
>   no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height
>   to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its
>   last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up
>   outside the parent.
>
> **Empty blocks**
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline content, height, or min-height
>   to separate a block's margin-top from its margin-bottom, then its top
>   and bottom margins collapse.

**Query a:** I need to understand the 3 rules that are applied in which sequence in the example below.

**Query b:** If for empty block element margins collapse, then it occurs as top or bottom margin for it ? You might say what difference it makes but then if I use outline as in example below, here it seems as if it is collapsed as top.

Basically I have 3 `<p>` elements in which middle one is empty.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ex1</title>
    <style>

        body{
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        p{
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            outline: 1px solid black;
        }

        #empty{
            margin: 20px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        The oldest classical Greek and Latin writing had little or no space between words, and could be written in boustrophedon (alternating directions). Over time, text direction (left to right) became standardized, and word dividers and terminal punctuation became common. The first way to divide sentences into groups was the original paragraphos, similar to an underscore at the beginning of the new group.[3] The Greek paragraphos evolved into the pilcrow (¶), which in English manuscripts in the Middle Ages can be seen inserted inline between sentences. The hedera leaf (e.g. ☙) has also been used in the same way.
    </p>
    <p id ='empty'></p>
    <p>
        The oldest classical Greek and Latin writing had little or no space between words, and could be written in boustrophedon (alternating directions). Over time, text direction (left to right) became standardized, and word dividers and terminal punctuation became common. The first way to divide sentences into groups was the original paragraphos, similar to an underscore at the beginning of the new group.[3] The Greek paragraphos evolved into the pilcrow (¶), which in English manuscripts in the Middle Ages can be seen inserted inline between sentences. The hedera leaf (e.g. ☙) has also been used in the same way.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that the final margin between the first and last paragraph is 20px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The margins of `#empty` collapse through, resulting in a 20px collapsed-through margin. This collapsed-through margin collapses with the 10px bottom margin of the first paragraph, and the 10px top margin of the last paragraph. This results in a 20px gap between the first and last paragraphs, since the collapsed-through margin is larger than either of their margins and therefore swallows them both.

Your observation is correct: `#empty`, when its collapsed through, is rendered with its top margin. From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> - *[...]* The position of the element's top border edge is the same as it would have been if the element had a non-zero bottom border.
>
> Note that the positions of elements that have been collapsed through have no effect on the positions of the other elements with whose margins they are being collapsed; the top border edge position is only required for laying out descendants of these elements.

The position that "would have been if the element had a non-zero bottom border" is the position of the element if the element's margins *did not* collapse through, since having a non-zero bottom border blocks the margins from collapsing through.

Comment: Is the sequence of steps you specified the only solution ?

Comment: @Breaking Benjamin: What do you mean by "sequence of steps" and what do you mean by "solution"? I didn't think there was a problem you were trying to solve here.

Comment: You mentioned how the rules are applied for collapsing margin. There you answered in some sequence. Ex:Step 1: The margins of #empty collapse through, resulting in a 20px collapsed-through margin. Step 2: This collapsed-through margin collapses with the 10px bottom margin of the first paragraph,and the 10px top margin of the last paragraph. I am asking if these steps sequence are the ONLY way or one of the possible ways to calculate this. I have one or more ways to achieve this final 20px . I want to know, in future, does order of these steps matter or not? By steps I mean those 3 basic rules.

Comment: @Breaking Benjamin: You could likewise say that each of #empty's 20px margins swallows its adjacent 10px margin before collapsing through, and you'd still get the same result. So order doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

> Query a: I need to understand the 3 rules that are applied in which sequence in the example below.

The sequence doesn't matter much as long as rules are not declared many times for the same selector with different value.

- border on body, will keep the verical margin from first and last child inside itself.
- empty paragraph has 0 height, margins will collapse/merge with previous and next sibblings, it will act as if it was not there. Add 1px of height to test behavior:

See snippet below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ex1</title>
    <style>

        body{
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        p{
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            outline: 1px solid black;
        }

        #empty{
            margin: 20px;
            height:1px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        The oldest classical Greek and Latin writing had little or no space between words, and could be written in boustrophedon (alternating directions). Over time, text direction (left to right) became standardized, and word dividers and terminal punctuation became common. The first way to divide sentences into groups was the original paragraphos, similar to an underscore at the beginning of the new group.[3] The Greek paragraphos evolved into the pilcrow (¶), which in English manuscripts in the Middle Ages can be seen inserted inline between sentences. The hedera leaf (e.g. ☙) has also been used in the same way.
    </p>
    <p id ='empty'></p>
    <p>
        The oldest classical Greek and Latin writing had little or no space between words, and could be written in boustrophedon (alternating directions). Over time, text direction (left to right) became standardized, and word dividers and terminal punctuation became common. The first way to divide sentences into groups was the original paragraphos, similar to an underscore at the beginning of the new group.[3] The Greek paragraphos evolved into the pilcrow (¶), which in English manuscripts in the Middle Ages can be seen inserted inline between sentences. The hedera leaf (e.g. ☙) has also been used in the same way.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

In my own Humble opinion, if an element is not drawn (height = 0 = null ), then outline should not be drawn either even when `display` is not set to `none`.

---

> Query b: If for empty block element margins collapse, then it occurs as top or bottom margin for it ? You might say what difference it makes but then if I use outline as in example below, here it seems as if it is collapsed as top.

Somehow with an height of 0 and **no Block formatting context reset**, the browser will still try its best to draw this outline when the element is actually drawn nowhere. it will draw the outline from top margin value where the element would stand if drawn.

SEE snippet below where BFC is triggered

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ex1</title>
  <style>
    body {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    p {
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      outline: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    #empty {
      margin: 20px;
      /* reset BFC  see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context*/
      display: table;
      /* overflow:hidden; resets also the BFC read the link provided to start understands how this works :) */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    The oldest classical Greek and Latin writing had little or no space between words, and could be written in boustrophedon (alternating directions). Over time, text direction (left to right) became standardized, and word dividers and terminal punctuation
    became common. The first way to divide sentences into groups was the original paragraphos, similar to an underscore at the beginning of the new group.[3] The Greek paragraphos evolved into the pilcrow (¶), which in English manuscripts in the Middle
    Ages can be seen inserted inline between sentences. The hedera leaf (e.g. ☙) has also been used in the same way.
  </p>
  <p id='empty'></p>
  <p>
    The oldest classical Greek and Latin writing had little or no space between words, and could be written in boustrophedon (alternating directions). Over time, text direction (left to right) became standardized, and word dividers and terminal punctuation
    became common. The first way to divide sentences into groups was the original paragraphos, similar to an underscore at the beginning of the new group.[3] The Greek paragraphos evolved into the pilcrow (¶), which in English manuscripts in the Middle
    Ages can be seen inserted inline between sentences. The hedera leaf (e.g. ☙) has also been used in the same way.
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why do you consider an element with zero height to be "not drawn" even when its display is not none?

Comment: @BoltClock because it uses no space and is flat down to 0 (put any units behind it , add background-color whatever) it is just not drawn cause there is nothing to draw :) . When it is a block you do not even have to deal with a line-height.  I also mention the block formating context in which behaviors comes different. (see test with display:table or overflow;hidden where top/bottom margins are there. There is something not coherent to my point of view. Or margins are drawn when bfc is triggered and also when not triggered or not at all :)  it's a funny compromise i think.

Comment: I guess you're talking about empty elements - because if the element isn't empty, then not drawing it would mean none of its contents, including absolutely positioned elements, would be rendered either. (Note that a non-empty element's margins can still collapse through if none of its descendants are in the flow - hence the last sentence in the quotation in my answer.)

Comment: @BoltClock i talked only about empty elements displayed as block , where here a <p> was involved in the question and where id="empty" was used to select in the test. BFC or not, behavior is different, i have no probleme with the BFC behavior (of empty block) i agree with because seems coherent, it is only when there is no BFC that it seems odd ... and only seen because of outline   ;)

Comment: @BoltClock if you mentionned the different behavior when BFC is triggered on the empty block element (top and bottom margin are rendered in that case), i would delete my answser , My english is too terrible to be clear :)